# extjs4 display tooltip on button click instead of mouse hover

Tags: javascript, extjs, tooltip, extjs4.1

I am trying to add a on click listener to the below tooltip.
I do not want the tooltip to display on mouse hover. Instead it need it show on button click.
Do I have to add a handler function inside a listener?

```
{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls:'my-btn',
                    iconCls:'question',                     
                    src:'../www/css/slate/btn/question.png',
                    padding: '5 0 0 0',

                    listeners: {


                        render: function(cmp) {
                            Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                                closable:true,
                                hideDelay : 3000,
                                padding: '0 0 0 0',
                                maxWidth:400,
                                width:800,

                                target: cmp.el,
                                html: "<b>read-only</b>:Users will have read only access to all pages",
                                getTargetXY: function() {
                                    return [810, 340];
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }


                },
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, on `click` you can show the tooltip programmatically, skip the `target` and add a `showAt()`:

```
...

listeners: {
    click: function(cmp) {
        Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            closable:true,
            hideDelay : 3000,
            padding: '0 0 0 0',
            maxWidth:400,
            width:800,
            html: "<b>read-only</b>:Users will have read only access to all pages",
        }).showAt([810, 340]);

    }
}
```

If you don't need the automatic hiding (your tooltip is closable anyway) you can make it just an `Ext.tip.Tip`:

```
        Ext.create('Ext.tip.Tip', {
            closable:true,
            padding: '0 0 0 0',
            maxWidth:400,
            width:800,
            html: "<b>read-only</b>:Users will have read only access to all pages",
        }).showAt([810, 340]);
```

Comment: you are giving static location to `showAt`, what if i want to display on dynamic position obtained from mouse click or a button??

Comment: Works exactly the same, just feed in the coordinates you want the tooltip to be shown.